# Como Exportar más rapido un datagridview a Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Tengo una aplicación en la cual en un dataGridView me muestra información de mi base de datos de sql server. Y yo, mediante un botón lo que hago es tomar esa información del dataGridView y la convierto a un Excel.

Hice un prueba con 6000 registros(filas) y se demora de 40-50 min, sé que tarda debido a que lo estoy desarrollando via COM/Interop y este proceso lo va realizando 1-1 y quisiera saber si me pueden aconsejar como mejorar la velocidad de exportacion, este es mi codigo:

```
        int filasTotales = tabla.Rows.Count;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
        int ColumnIndex = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
        {
            ColumnIndex++;
            excel.Cells[1, ColumnIndex] = col.Name;
        }
        int RowIndex = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows)
        {
            RowIndex++;
            ColumnIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
            {
                ColumnIndex++;
                excel.Cells[RowIndex + 1, ColumnIndex] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
            }

            progress.Value = (RowIndex * 100) / filasTotales;
        }
        excel.Visible = true;
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Activate();
```

Realmente les agradeceria que me ayudaran

Comment: Cree una tabla con 5 columnas y 6000 registros, copie y pegue tu código, y a mí me demora 26 segundos en crear el excel

Comment: @Yussef perdón se me olvido mencionar que mi base de datos es de 33 columnas y 6000 registros

Comment: Con 40 columnas me demora 4min 55seg, que encuentro es demasiado pero es 10 veces menos lo que señalas tu. Que versión de .net usas y que versión del interop??

Comment: @Yussef es un proyecto de Windows Forms App(.NET Framework) 4.8 y Microsoft Excel 16.0

Comment: Ok, yo estoy ocupando .net 7.0 y el interop es el 15, si encuentro algo de tiempo trataré de probar con la 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios, yo estoy ocupando .net 7 e interop 15, con tú código y 6mil registros con 40 columnas demora 5min aprox.

Con el siguiente código demora 3 segundos

```
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

object[,] datos = new object[dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1, dataGridView1.Columns.Count]; // +1 por la cabecera
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) //cabeceras
{
    datos[0, j] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name;
}


for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        datos[i + 1, j] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
    }
    progressBar1.Value++;
}

excel.Range[excel.Cells[1, 1], excel.Cells[datos.GetLength(0), datos.GetLength(1)]].Value = datos;
excel.Visible = true;
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Activate();
timer.Stop();
var elapsed = timer.Elapsed;
MessageBox.Show(elapsed.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff"));
```

Lo que hice fue crear un array bidimensional de objetos y pasar los datos de `DataGridView` a ese array. Luego seleccione un rango en el excel y copie de golpe (en un solo paso) todo el contenido.

Traté de dejar el código lo más parecido al tuyo para que se entendiera

*El `timer` que está en el código es solo para medir los tiempos, tú debes quitarlo*

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, no lo he probado pero es lo que estaba buscando, despues te comparto si me funciono, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score -1):

En C# uso `@using ClosedXML.Excel;`

y para la creacion del excel me queda algo asi

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
            try
            {
//Creamos una tabla
                var respuestasTable = respuestas.Select(respuestaTable => new
                {
                    respuestaTable.Id,
                    respuestaTable.Nombre,                                      
                });
//Insertamos la tabla en la hoja de Excel 
  workbook.AddWorksheet("Reporte").FirstCell().InsertTable(respuestasTable);

//Cambiamos nombres de columnas

                workbook.Worksheet("Reporte").Cell("A1").Value = "Id";
                
//Asignamos la ruta donde se guardara

                string folder = @"D:\\Carpeta\\Documentos\\Reportes";
                string folderPath = (folder + @"\Reporte.xlsx");
//Guardamos el documento en la ubicacion
                    workbook.SaveAs(folderPath);

                StateHasChanged();
            }       
        }
```

Espero te sirva

Quedo pendiente ante cualquier duda

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? No te guíes solo por el título... Lee [answer].